# javascript runtime error object doesn't support property or method 'tabs'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Whenever i load my page this error got hit.
My code is:

```
<head runat="server">
   <title>Jai Jinendera</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5.js"></script>
<script src="js/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/all-in-one-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/setup.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.carouFredSel.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    });

    $(function () {
        $('#work').carouFredSel({
            width: '100%',
            scroll: 1,
            auto: false,
            pagination: false,
            prev: '.prev_item',
            next: '.next_item'
        });

        $("#work").touchwipe({
            wipeLeft: function () { $('.next_item').trigger('click'); },
            wipeRight: function () { $('.prev_item').trigger('click'); }
        });
    });

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#demo-side-bar').removeAttr('style');
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.demobar {
    display:none;
}
#demo-side-bar {
    top:53px!important;
    left:90%!important;
    display:block!important;
}
</style>
</head>
```

It says error in client/js/setup.js-line 10 column 5

and 10th line of setup.js is

$('.tabs').tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 'fast'} });

Comment: Why are you including a second copy of jquery.min.js?

Comment: You don't close the caroufredsel `<script>` tag properly. You also need to start a new one.

Comment: Fascinating.
So uh, what does the element with the class "tabs" look like in code again?

Comment: jQuery UI has easing in them. The 1.3 version you include is just duplicated and imo deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems in your `<script>` declarations:

1. You have included `jquery.min.js` twice, once from a location on your server and once from Google's CDN. Remove the latter. (Or remove the former and move the latter up to replace it.)
2. A `<script>` element should either reference an external script or contain content of its own, but *not both.*

You need to move the code out of your `jquery.carouFredSel.js` script element:

```
<script src="jquery.carouFredSel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...and then include that code in a new script element:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function () {
   ...
</script>
```

P.S. I don't know what you have in `all-in-one-min.js`, but it clearly *isn't* actually *all* in one or you wouldn't need the other scripts.